# Compatibility between atomic operations in different C libraries

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, atomic, c11

A classical synchronization idiom between two threads (producer and consumer) involves

- A producer updating a value in shared memory (`global_variable`), and then updating an atomic flag (`flag`) with release semantics. In C11 the producer code could be written as follows:

  ```
  global_variable = 0; 
  atomic_store_explicit(&flag, 1, memory_order_release); // flag is an integer
  ```
- A consumer waiting for the value of `flag` to become 1, and then reading `global_variable`. If the consumer has been written using the GCC atomic library it would look like:

  ```
  while (__atomic_load_n(&flag, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE) != 1; // loop until flag enabled
  // read value of global_variable
  ```

If the consumer code is written using explicit C11 atomic loads we would expect the program to be correct...but is the GCC "equivalent" code guaranteed to work too? In other words, The question becomes: are atomic operations defined in different libraries compatible? The [GCC atomics documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) is vague to that respect:

> The following built-in functions approximately match the requirements for C++11 memory model

Comment: What "different" implementations are you talking about? The gcc internal `__atomic` stuff should be exactly the same as the C11 API that is provided by it. But your question is not very clear, what is about the C++ stuff that you are mentioning?

Comment: Compatibility between GCC and C11 atomic operations, for example. You are assuming that they are exactly the same, but note the "approximately" part of the GCC documentation I cited. Does for example `__atomic_load_n(&flag, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE)` (GCC) have the exact same semantics as `atomic_load_explicit(&flag, memory_order_acquire)`(C11) ?